# Django Filter by Multiple Foreign Key Properties

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, matching

So I have Django models which look like the following:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    cool_prop = models.CharField()

class Metadata(models.Model):
     key = models.CharField()
     value = models.CharField()
     test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
```

and I would like to be able to filter tests based on if they contain a key:value pair based on this metadata. Essentially, I would like to be able to do:

```
tests = Test.objects.all().filter(metadata__key=key and metadata__value=value)
```

But I'm unsure how to perform this in Django. I've looked into F and Q statements. It seems as though most Django operations would allow any tests that has ANY metadata with said key and ANY metadata with said value. But I need the tests where 1 metadata matches in both key and value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are testing only 1 set, it is just a simple:

```
tests = Test.objects.filter(metadata__key=key, metadata__value=value)
```

If you want to match a bunch of key-value pairs,

```
#Assuming that the keyvalue pairs is in a dictionary,
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

k_v_pairs = (Q(metadata__key=key, metadata__value=value) for key, value in k_v_dictionary)
tests = Test.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, k_v_pairs)).distinct()
```

Basically, it is the equivalent of saying get me the queryset of `Test` which have any of the following key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a subquery for matching metadata objects:

```
metadata = Metadata.objects.filter(key=key, value=value)
tests = Test.objects.filter(metadata__in=metadata).distinct()
```